# Using angular 1 component inside of angular 2 app

Tags: angularjs, angular

What is the best way to use an angular 1 component inside of an angular 2 app? There are resources on how to migrate from 1 to 2, but seemingly no up-to-date approaches of using angularJs components inside of an angular app. I'm sure it's possible with the upgradeAdapter, but not entirely sure what the implementation would look like.

Comment: Care to explain the downvote? I've already said that I'm aware of the linked documentation.

Comment: I never said that it's desirable, I'm fully aware that it is not ideal. I am simply exploring this path with respect to business needs. I've clearly stated that I am aware of the available resources out there. If my question is not phrased correctly, make a recommendation on how I can improve it or make at least some sort attempt at a valuable contribution instead of being so arrogant. Instead of saying that "it's worst to do...", why not give a constructive answer backed with some details/facts/information/etc. so that me and the rest of the community with a similar issue can learn?

Comment: it's my problem as well.  i thought from the angular document that i can include angular1 component inside angular2.  but it seems i misunderstood it, instead the angular1 should be an application itself rather than just a component. or did i misunderstand it again? :) anyway, some people will just downvote because they really don't know the answer, i guess.